# Android menu items are not showing up at once

Tags: android, menuitem, android-support-library, android-actionbaractivity

I have two menu items: Settings and Exit.  When I run my code, with both set to showAsAction:"always", none of them show up on the screen when I press the menu button on my phone. This also happens if I set both to "ifRoom". However, if I set one to "never", the other one will show up. How can I get both items to show up? I am running a ~3.5 inch android 4.1.2 phone.  I am using the `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` theme.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/sun"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/exit_the_app"
        android:title="@string/options_exit_text"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:icon="@drawable/night"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

This is the screen when both items are set to "always" or "ifRoom", no menu items show up:
[image: two muppets]
This is the screen when settings is set to "never", the exit item shows up:
[image: ttwtw]
There seems to be enough room, so how do I make both items show up? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When showAsAction is set to ifRoom or always the item is shown in the action bar instead of the overflow menu (only if there's room in the case of ifRoom). This is the expected behavior.

If you want them to both show up in the overflow menu, set showAsAction to never for both.

I suggest reading the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html